# Failed to emit module BC36970 Visual Basic AND VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have method to fill DataGridView from SQL server database between tow dates my date column date in database is Date in this format "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", and this is the query:

```
Const sql As String = "SELECT * FROM money_sent WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-08-01 04:01:59.000' AND '2016-09-10 04:02:05.000'"
```

until now everything perfect , when I tried to use datetimepicker I get 2 errors:

"Constant expression is required"(for picker 1)

"Constant expression is required"(for picker 2)

```
Const sql As String = "SELECT * FROM money_sent WHERE date BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "'"
```

After this I tried to do this:

```
    Dim date1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim date2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Const sql As String = "SELECT * FROM money_sent WHERE date BETWEEN '" & date1 & "' AND '" & date2 & "'"
```

Now I getting this error:

Failed to emit module'WindowsApplication.exe' (BC36970 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET Failed to emit module.)

What I can do in this situation please help

This is the method code :

```
If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Conn.Close()
    End If
    Conn.Open()
    Dim date1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim date2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Const sql As String = "SELECT * FROM money_sent WHERE date BETWEEN '" & date1 & "' AND '" & date2 & "'"

    Dim adt As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    adt.Fill(dt)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        MetroGrid2.Rows.Add()
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(1)
        Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        cell.Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(2)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(3)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(4)
        'DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = "DELETE"
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(5)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(6)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(7)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(8)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(9)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(10)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(12)
        MetroGrid2.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(0)
    Next
    Conn.Close()
```

Comment: Change the sql variable to a `String` not a `Const`... For example `Dim sql As String` A constant shouldn't change and by using a DateTime picker the value does change and isn't constant...

Comment: I feel like I'm stupid now :'
thank you.